# Match tags in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, tags

I wanted to know how can you search in tags p.s.
I have a table where there is a column for tags "bar,barmen,drink".

In search for example people search for barmen drink, how do I match this, I tried 
LIKE, INSTR() but no luck, the point is that tags column content doesn't have spaces between.
It's like "bar,barmen,drink" not like "bar, barmen, drink"

Any help..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem inherent with this type of design. Short of changing how you store the data, you'd have to do a search like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE CONCAT(',', tags, ',') LIKE '%,bar,%';
```

EDIT: Actually, I just double-checked, and you can use regexp like so:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]bar[[:>:]]';
```

Which should be quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 4):

Why not have a separate `tags` table, with

```
id int(11) auto_increment
post_id int(11)
tag text
```

Then, have one `tags` row for each tag.

Comment: I do agree that it should be moved into a new table for indexing, searching and general normalization!

Comment: I do have tags in other table, but I don't have them separated by ", " (comma and space) only "," (coma)" and that makes hard to use LIKE or INSTR

Comment: Now I understand what you mean..., your idea is the best way.