# How do I select rows where a column contains

Tags: mysql, sql

here is the field in my table

[image: service_field]

how do I select rows where a column contains only 5, not 15
if `SELECT *  FROM`vendor`WHERE`services`LIKE '%5%'` it will select that have 15 too.
any idea?

Comment: If you have control over your database structure, it's in need of [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regexp:

```
SELECT * FROM `VENDOR` WHERE `services` REGEXP '[[:<:]]5[[:>:]]';
```

(I just recently answered this in [Match tags in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158778/match-tags-in-mysql/7158828#7158828))

Answer (score 5):

As other comments noted, normalize your database. But, here's a hack to get what you're looking for temporarily:

```
select * from vendor where ',' + services + ',' like '%,5,%'
```

Comment: Thats what the ',' surrounding services does. If its only 5, it makes the column data ",5," and, therefore, finds ,5,.

Comment: @Derek Oh, I see what 'ya did there.  +1 for being clever

Answer (score 1):

select * from vendor where services = '5' OR services LIKE '5,%' OR services like '%,5' OR services LIKE '%,5,%'

But seriously normalize the DB

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`regexp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
select * from my_table
    where 
    my_col regexp '^5$' or
    my_col regexp ',5$' or
    my_col regexp ',5,';
```

Haven't tried the above expression myself, but something like that would work.

**EDIT:** with one regexp:

```
select * from my_table
    where 
    my_col regexp '^5$|,5$|,5,'
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually MySQL provides a `FIND_IN_SET` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for such comma-separated strings. This is simpler and cleaner than complex `like` or regexp solutions:

```
mysql> select * from vendor where find_in_set('5', services) > 0;
+----+----------+
| id | services |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 5        |
|  3 | 9,5      |
+----+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But still beware - such design could result in low performance.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in `where` condition you can write `services='5' or services like '%,5' or services like '%,5,%' or services like '5,%'`